# Flutter : image not being found

Tags: flutter, assets

This is my widget to display a little pic of myself in the app.

```
Widget image() {
    return CircleAvatar(
      radius: 50.0,
      backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/me.jpeg'),
    );
  }
```

Yet, for some reason, I keep getting this

```
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/me.jpeg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:668:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:651:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:504:13)
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/me.jpeg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#14309(), name: "images/me.jpeg", scale: 1.0)
```

Although the image is inside the folder. Please help

Comment: did you add the image path to pubspec.ymal file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you added the images to pubspec.yaml file and then run pub get

```
  assets:
    - images/me.jpeg
```